# In Excel and Word, is it possible to open the browse window immediately when opening a file?

Tags: windows, office365

When I'm using Word or Excel and I want to open a file, I always get a screen giving me the option to open a recent file, a file shared with me, a file from my OneDrive, this PC, add a location, and then finally to browse for a file on my harddrive.

Recent files comes in handy from time to time, yet 99% of the time I'm forced to click browse for file, making this entire screen basically useless for me.

Is there a way to have the browse window open immediately after selecting file-open? I've had a look at the following question: [Is there a quicker way to open/import a file in Excel 2013?](https://superuser.com/questions/806171/is-there-a-quicker-way-to-open-import-a-file-in-excel-2013) and tried the method described (check the box for Don't show the backstage when opening or saving a file, also Check Save to Computer by default), but it doesn't work in Office 365 (or I'm doing something wrong).

I did NOT check the default location to "my documents" (since I never use "my documents" to save anything, and because I don't have any default location to store documents (a default location to me is like saying I don't know where I should store this, so I'll just throw it on the pile - if there's not a dedicated folder for this document, I don't need to save it, but that's just my way of thinking).

Long story, short question: can I have File/Open point to the "browse window"?

Thanks!